# How to use ternary operator in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to use ternary operator in `func printThis(_ items: Any...)` :

```
import Foundation

class PrintHelper {

/// This will help us to stop printing any thing to the console if we want at any time to look for something important.
static var printIsAllowed: Bool {
    return true // set false to stop printing ..
}

/// Print method that check if print is allowed or not.
///
/// - Parameter items: Zero or more items to print.
static func printThis(_ items: Any...) {
    if printIsAllowed {
        print(items)
    }else{
        return
    }
}
```

I tried to shortcut this :

```
if printIsAllowed {
        print(items)
    }else{
        return
    }
```

by writing this :

`printIsAllowed ? print(items) : return`

Then a got an error!

Comment: That is not a place to use `?:`. Just get rid of `else { return }`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a ternary operator here or even *else*.  This is enough:

```
static func printThis(_ items: Any...) {
    if printIsAllowed {
        print(items)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really, *really*, want to use the ternary operator, change this function:

```
static func printThis(_ items: Any...) {
    let _ = printIsAllowed ? {print(items)}() : ()
}
```

And you can call it like so:

```
PrintHelper.printThis("Hello World!") //prints ["Hello World!"]
```

Comment: `_ = printIsAllowed ? print(items) : ()` is sufficient, but this is *really not recommended*

Comment: @vacawama yes, the comment by rmaddy is the real answer.